# Could not parse the remainder django template

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have a condition within a loop in my template like this:

```
{% for message in message_trash %}
<td><a href="#">
   {% if request.session.user_email == message.message_user_reciever.user_email %}
       {{ message.message_user_reciever.user_firstName }} {{ message.message_user_reciever.user_lastName }}
   {% elif request.session.user_email == message.message_user_sender.user_email %}
       {{ message.message_user_sender.user_firstName }} {{ message.message_user_sender.user_lastName }}
   {% endif %}
</a><small><a href="#">Friends</a></small></td>
{% endfor %}
```

but i don't know why i get this error when applying the url?

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '==message.message_user_reciever.user_email' from 'request.session.user_email==message.message_user_reciever.user_email'
```

## Update:

this is the view and variables that i render to the template:

```
def trashMessages(request, userId):
    if isMessageOwner(request, userId):
        user = Users.objects.get(user_id=userId)
        message_trash = Messages.objects.filter(Q(message_user_reciever= user, message_sender_type='TRASH') | Q(message_user_sender=user, message_reciever_type='TRASH'))
        return render(request, 'navigation_messages.html', {'user': user, 'message_trash': message_trash, 'type': 'trash'})
```

Comment: can u paste your view code.

Comment: @Also your Message model please, to check its attributes.

Comment: Most likely not the cause but do you have a typo.. reciever = receiver ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On testing your code out, I can only replicate your issue is by swapping:

```
{% if request.session.user_email == message.message_user_reciever.user_email %}
```

for

```
{% if request.session.user_email ==message.message_user_reciever.user_email %}
```

Note the missing space. Is the snippet in your question **exactly** as it is in your template?